How to improve the performance of the query in SQL Server to shift up values from non empty columns to empty columns?
I have a table Values
Values table:



ArtId
VarId
Sequence
Val1
Val2
Val3
Val4
Val5
Val6
Val7
Val8
Val9
Val10




1
1
1


A1-Val3









2
1
2





A2-Val6






3
2
3
A3-Val1











4
2
4



A4-Val4




A4-Val9



5
3
5

A5-Val2


A5-Val5








The values are shifted up based on VarId. For VarId = 1, there are 2 rows. Entry from column Val3 is shifted to Val1 and this will be same for all records having VarId = 1. So, the next value, ie A2-Val6 from column Val6 is shifted to next free column for VarId = 1. In this case it is the column Val2.
The final expected results for tables are
Expected Values table:



ArtId
VarId
Sequence
Val1
Val2
Val3
Val4
Val5
Val6
Val7
Val8
Val9
Val10




1
1
1
A1-Val3











2
1
2

A2-Val6










3
2
3
A3-Val1











4
2
4

A4-Val4
A4-Val9









5
3
5
A5-Val2
A5-Val5











Above tables are samples. Actual tables contains more than 1 Million records and number of columns can be upto maximum 100. (I know, it is not good to have that many columns in a table, but couldn't change that).
I implemented the solution and it is returning expected result. But, I want to improve the performance when there is large volume of data.
DECLARE @start INT = 1, @end INT = 10

DECLARE @valueTable NVARCHAR(100) = N'[Values]'

DECLARE @valueColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

DECLARE @numColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)= N''
DECLARE @numColumnsWithoutNull NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

DECLARE @attNumber NVARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @separator VARCHAR(1) = ','

WHILE @start <= @end
BEGIN
    
    SET @attNumber = CAST(@start AS NVARCHAR(3))  
    
    IF @start = @end
    BEGIN
        SET @separator = N''
    END
   
    SET @valueColumns += N'Val'+ @attNumber +''+@separator+''
            
    SET @numColumns += N'['+ @attNumber +']'+@separator+''
    SET @numColumnsWithoutNull += N'ISNULL(['+ @attNumber +'],'''') AS ['+ @attNumber +']'+@separator+''       

    SET @start = @start +1
END        

DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX) =N'
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempCache;
SELECT * INTO #TempCache
FROM
(
    SELECT  ArtId, VarId, Sequence, '+@numColumnsWithoutNull+'
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  VarId, ArtId, Sequence, Value, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY VariationGroupId ORDER BY [Cols]) AS RowId
        FROM
            (SELECT * FROM '+@valueTable+' ) AS T1
        UNPIVOT
            (value FOR [Cols] IN ('+@valueColumns+')) AS unpvt  
        WHERE Value <> ''''
    ) T
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([value]) FOR RowId IN ('+@numColumns+')
    ) AS pvt
) Temp;
TRUNCATE TABLE '+@valueTable+';

INSERT INTO '+@valueTable+'
SELECT * FROM #TempCache 
ORDER BY Sequence
'
--SET STATISTICS XML ON;
exec sp_executesql @result
--SET STATISTICS XML OFF;


Is it necessary for the table names to be in variables?

Real time scenario creates tables with combination of multiple variables.

The problem here is that you're not using tables right. If you have multiple columns containing the same (logical) type of data, that's a normalisation failure. The right table would have ArtId, VarId, Sequence, Val and X, where X can take the values 1-10 and is whatever name is appropriate for the data that's been mismodelled as metadata and embedded into these Val column names.

You can take advantage of a function like json_array() that can strip null values, the algorithms would be:
at the innermost level of subqueries:
select ArtId, VarId, Sequence,json_array(Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5, Val6, Val7, Val8, Val9, Val10) as js
from values 


next level, you calculate the size of the array
next level, you "sum(array_size) over(partition by varid order by sequence)"
next level, you generate an "header" array of sum_array_size of ' '
next level you merge the "lag(header) over(partition by varid order by
sequence)" with the "js" array of values

the result should be:
1   1   1   ["A1-Val3"]
2   1   2   [" ","A2-Val6"]
3   2   3   ["A3-Val1"]
4   2   4   [" ","A4-Val4","A4-Val9"]
5   3   5   ["A5-Val2","A5-Val5"]

Then you can use that query as the source in a MERGE statement, updating the original columns using JSON_VALUE(result_array, '$[N]'), with N from 0 to N cols-1.
And so you have a pure SQL solution.

Thank you for the reply. Unfortunaltely, JSON_ARRAY() is available from Sql Server 2022 only. We are using Sql Server 2019.  I forgot to mention the version in the tag. I've updated the tag with the version also.

... and json_arrayagg only in Azur version + the joining of JSON array also may be a difficulty in SQLServer… I tried to make it in DBfiddle but without success, it's much easier to write in ORACLE.

You may try the same logic with XML data...

This is horribly normalised data. So usually the best thing to do is to use one or more CTEs to transform the data into a properly normalised structure, then computed the result in a reasonably straightforward manner and then (if you really have to) transform it back into the denormalised form.
So something like this1:
declare @Duff table (ArtId int, VarId int, Sequence int, Val1 varchar(10), Val2 varchar(10), Val3 varchar(10), Val4 varchar(10), Val5 varchar(10), Val6 varchar(10), Val7 varchar(10), Val8 varchar(10), Val9 varchar(10), Val10 varchar(10));
insert into @Duff(ArtId, VarId, Sequence, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5, Val6, Val7, Val8, Val9, Val10) values
(1, 1, 1,null,null,'A1-Val3',null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
(2, 1, 2,null,null,null,null,null,'A2-Val6',null,null,null,null),
(3, 2, 3,'A3-Val1',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null),       
(4, 2, 4,null,null,null,'A4-Val4',null,null,null,null,'A4-Val9',null),
(5, 3, 5,null,'A5-Val2',null,null,'A5-Val5',null,null,null,null,null);

With CorrectlyNormalised as (
    select ArtId, VarId, Sequence, Val, CAST(SUBSTRING(X, 4, 10) as int) as X
    from
        @Duff d
            unpivot (Val for X in (Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5, Val6, Val7, Val8, Val9, Val10)) u
), Renumbered as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VarId ORDER BY Sequence, X) as rn
    from CorrectlyNormalised
), DenormalisedAgain as (
    select ArtId, VarId, Sequence, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]
    from
        Renumbered
            pivot (MIN(Val) for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])) a
)
select
    ArtId, VarId, Sequence, MIN([1]), MIN([2]), MIN([3]), MIN([4]), MIN([5]), MIN([6]), MIN([7]), MIN([8]), MIN([9]), MIN([10])
from
    DenormalisedAgain
group by ArtId, VarId, Sequence

Which produces this result:
ArtId       VarId       Sequence                                                                                                       
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           1           1           A1-Val3    NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
2           1           2           NULL       A2-Val6    NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
3           2           3           A3-Val1    NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
4           2           4           NULL       A4-Val4    A4-Val9    NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
5           3           5           A5-Val2    A5-Val5    NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL

You can change the final query to select from each separate CTE to see how the data is being transformed at each step. I'm using MIN in a couple of places where I know that I'm only going to see one input value but the statement requires an aggregate. Helpfully, MIN passed only a single value always returns that value.

1Notice how I've restructured your sample data as a declare table and insert statements - it's both about as compact as how you presented it in your question and it's runnable and usable as sample data. Please consider using this form to present sample data in any future SQL questions.
Note also that I had to guess at the types

Thank you for your time. I'll try to improve my way of framing the questions. I tried to implement your solution and I got the expected result ( The solution that I implemented also gave the expected result). But regarding the performance, both solutions took almost similar time.
